# Crystal report error message

Tags: vb.net, crystal-reports

ive been dealing with a kind of no error message my application is throwing after the setup has been installed on my machine. 
The application run fine and generate a report exactly the way i want it. The problem is that after compiling it as set up, it throw this message:

```
System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x80000000);
No error.
at
CrystalDesisionsReportAppServer.Controllers.DatabaseControllerClass.ReplaceConnection(Object oldConnection, Object newConnection, Object parameterFields, Object crDBOptionUseDefault)
at
CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.ReportDocument.SetDataSourceInternal(Object val, Type type)
at 
CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.ReportDocument.SetDataSource(DataSet dataSet)
at Presby_Soft.reportFrm.reportFrm_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e)
```

this is the code im using:

```
Private Sub reportFrm_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        If conn.State = ConnectionState.Closed Then
            conn.Open()
        End If

        Try
            Dim rpt As New CrystalReport1()
            Dim da As New SQLiteDataAdapter
            Dim ds As New presbydbDataSet


            'Dim cmd As New SQLiteCommand("SELECT personal_details.fn, training.training_level FROM personal_details INNER JOIN training ON personal_details.Staff_ID ='" + detailsFrm.Label13.Text + "'", conn)


            Dim cmd As New SQLiteCommand("SELECT * FROM personal_details WHERE personal_details.staff_ID='" + detailsFrm.Label13.Text + "'", conn)

            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
            da.SelectCommand = cmd
            da.Fill(ds, "personal_details")
            rpt.Subreports.Item("persoRpt").SetDataSource(ds)

            CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = rpt



        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.ToString)
        End Try

        conn.Close()
    End Sub
```

Please help, I really don't know how to go about this problem. Thanks for answering

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I managed to get rid of this problem. The issue is that i was adding the business object files directly into the bin folder while the business object is already installed on the computer. I just removed the business object files i added and the application worked fine.